# Why am I able to import my JS in different ways?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

My folder structure :

```
--public
----frontend.js
--views
----fontend.ejs
```

frontend.js inside public folder and frontend.ejs inside views folder.

In the html / ejs file I linked the javascript (frontend.js) like this

```
<script src="/frontend.js"></script>
```

Instead of this

```
<script src="../public/frontend.js"></script>
```

and it still works , why?

Comment: Express points `/` to public folder - `app.use(express.static('public'))`

Answer (score 2):

Check your `app.js` in your express project, `express.static` is getting used to serve `public` folder for `/` by default. .

Exact syntax doing this -

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```